# LibSVM Predict Not working

Tags: python, c++, opencv, libsvm

I've coded my classifer in libsvm's python utility, and it has worked quite well so far. Here is an example of how I call my Python API:

```
print svmutil.svm_predict([2], [f.flatten().tolist()], libsvm_model, '-b 1')
```

where f is a (1024,1) vector.

I have saved the model, and loaded it using the C++ API. However, when I attempt to load and predict the same vector, it gives me wrong results.

```
cv::Mat oneCol = fcMat.row(0);
svm_node *x = (struct svm_node *) malloc(1025*sizeof(struct svm_node));
for(int i=0; i<1024; i++){
    x[i].index = i;
    x[i].value = (double)oneCol.at<float>(i);
}
x[1024].index = -1;


double *prob_estimates=NULL;
prob_estimates = (double *) malloc(svmModel->nr_class*sizeof(double));

double retVal = svm_predict_probability(svmModel, x, prob_estimates);
cout << retVal << endl;

for(int j=0;j<svmModel->nr_class;j++)
    cout << prob_estimates[j] << endl;
```

Over here, I attempt to load a vector in from an OpenCV object as such. However, the predicted model comes out wrong. Is something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<1024; i++){
    x[i].index = i+1;
    x[i].value = (double)oneCol.at<float>(i);
}
```

In LibSVM, indexes start at 1. Who knew :(